# Best practice to draw site plan in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a `WPF` application which provides the possibility to draw something like site plan. Users can `drag and drop` predefined objects from object panel to this plan, resize and rotate them or create and save their own objects. What approach should I use to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you say about placing **predefined objects** into another object one possibility could be to use a **Canvas control**.
Here you have a very simple [tutorial about the Canvas Panel](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html) and also the [reference to the canvas class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netframework-4.8) which states :

> Defines an area within which you can explicitly position child elements by using coordinates that are relative to the Canvas area.

I hope it's what you are looking for.